# Android, ViewFlipper - setViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-studio, viewflipper

I'm trying to create an indicator for my ViewFlipper slider. For ViewPager we can use the method setViewPager(), but for ViewFlipper I'm getting an error. Here is the code sample of indicator.

```
myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myflipper);
CirclePageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById (R.id.circlePageIndicator);
mIndicator.setViewFlipper(myViewFlipper);
```

I checked the ViewFlipper class on the android developer website. There is no such method. This is just illustration for my coming question.

So, my question is how can I do this? Is there any equivalent method for ViewFlipper to set my indicator?

Comment: I found The Class for [CirclePageIndicator](https://github.com/kevintanhongann/Android-ViewFlipperIndicator/blob/master/ViewFlipperIndicatorSample/src/main/java/com/viewflipperindicator/sample/CirclePagerActivity.java)